# iTunes 12 crashing during ios 8 install

Tags: ios, itunes, ios8

iTunes 12 crashing during ios 8 install. When phone is connected itunes 12 will crash. 
What to do about this? 
I tried reverting my itunes to 11 but whenever i open itunes it asks to update to 12 or quit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what worked for me is to use another computer with iTunes 11 to install ios 8.

Comment: Thanks! I spent a lot of time downgrading my itunes.